# reactjs or reactive-native application for ipod using Honewell Captuvo sled

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Good Morning,

I would like to create a reactjs or react-native application, whichever is most applicable, for an ipod that is within a Honeywell Captuvo sled (this provides a fully functional barcode scanner, and locks the device to help prevent theft).

The only programming plugin I can find for the sled, is a cordova one:

https://github.com/BlueFletch/cordova-plugin-honeywell-captuvo

Being new to react programming, I am not quite sure what environment I can use that would allow me to be able to tap into this plugin to integrate retrieving data from the barcode scanner within my application.

Any help in understanding my options that would work with this, would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Jim